# Database Design: how to model a table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Say I want each user of my application to be able to specify a number of columns and rows, then assign certain values within each cell. Basically, I want them to be able to create tabular data -- like a spreadsheet.

A good example would be the seating assignments within a theater. A theater's seat can probably be represented within a grid. Some cells will not have seats, some will have seats. Some seats may be for VIP, some for the disabled, some for regular customers.

How do I model such information?

Comment: Another hint would be , that there is a fundamental difference between a spreadsheet and a database table [A thorough description can be found here](http://nrimp.dfw.state.or.us/nrimp/feature/2003/12-2003.htm) Also the answer from zerkms looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store number of rows and columns for each "sheet" in one table, and the data in another. The latter would look like

```
rownum | colnum | value
```

If you're specifically writing an application for theaters - just add needed properties there:

```
rownum | colnum | sold (bool) | available (bool) | is_vip (bool)
```

Comment: Hi zerkms, your solution is very similar to Michael Durrant's. Will this scale? Is this the proper way to model a grid/spreadsheet/table?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: `will this scale?` question makes no sense in an abstract. If you'll shard it among a lot of servers - yes, it will.

Answer (score 0):

Me personally here's how I'd represent it:

- Row (Integer)
- Column (Integer)
- Value (String, or anything really)

And then I'd make the primary key (Row, Column) and maybe additional indices as needed.